# Array Program for Searching a Specific number in Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

I have just learned 1D Array in Java, and I wrote a code to take input from the user for a specific array length, and then print the users entered data.
After that user writes a number to check if the number is present or not in the array.

I have the desired output, but in one place I couldn't understand the logic. Please guide me.

Here is the program:

```
    //Program to get value from user using array and print all the values

import java.util.Scanner;
class Array{
public static void main(String args[]){

int[] a = new int[5];
System.out.println("Enter 5 Numbers to Store in a Array");
for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
a[i] = in.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Numbers you Entered are:\n");
for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
System.out.println(a[i]);
}

System.out.println("Check if the number is present in the array or not:");
Scanner ing = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = ing.nextInt();

**if(input == a[4]**){
System.out.println("Number is found");
}
else{
System.out.println("Not Found");
}

}
}
```

and the output:

```
    Enter 5 Numbers to Store in an Array
56
45
78
79
80
Numbers you Entered are:

56
45
78
79
80
Check if the number is present in the array or not:
80
Number is found
```

**I want to know why the number is found in the array size is a[4], because I have the array size a[5]**.

Comment: An array start at index 0 si if you have an array of length 5 the indexes are 0,1,2,3,4. You want check if a number is in the array but you check just one index is it normal ?

Comment: @OmarAldakar sorry I have just realized my logic was wrong. Thanks for answering. a[4] means it is only printing the 5th position. And I have entered 80 which is in 5th pos.

Comment: @OmarAldakar can I use for loop to traverse each element and then print the required number? Like this: for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
if(input == a[i]){
System.out.println("Number is found");
}
else{
System.out.println("Not Found");
}
}
}

Comment: Yes but not like this, you need to store in a boolean to know if you have seen or not the number at the end of the loop.

Comment: For example : boolean x = false; for(...){if(...){x = true}} then at the end of the loop you do if(x) {print('yes my number')} else print('no number ...'). Otherwise you will print not found for each numbers of the list that is not your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since arrays are Zero based indexing,so the position which you have found for value 80 is 4

Please refer this [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm]

Comment: I have just realized my wrong logic. Thank you for answering

Comment: Okay,If its helped you , please upvote or accept it